# Copy columns by header using name. Help me pls

Tags: vba, excel

I having difficulty copying specific columns into another sheet.

```
Sub FindthenCopy()
    'Excel VBA find the position of a header
    Dim source As Range
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("CheckSheet")
    For i = 1 To 50
        If Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(1, i).Value = "User ID" Then
            Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Columns(i).Select
            Set source = Selection
            source.Copy ([ws1])
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Also tell us what the actual problem is - "having difficulty" doesn't tell us anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're specifying the destination as a worksheet, it needs to be a cell

```
 source.Copy ([ws1])
```

should be

```
 source.copy ws1.range("A1")  'or whichever column you want - must be row 1 though
```

Answer (score 2):

as @HarassedDad already told you, you must specify a starting cell in thebsheet you want to past values

furthermore `ActiveSheet` is the default implicit sheet reference assumed and you don't need all that `Select` and `Selection`:

```
Sub FindthenCopy()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("CheckSheet")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 50
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "User ID" Then
            Columns(i).Copy ws1.Cells(1, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

you may also want to use `Find()` method and avoid looping:

```
Sub FindthenCopy()
    Dim source As Range

    Set source = Rows(1).Find(what:="User ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not source Is Nothing Then source.EntireColumn.Copy Worksheets("CheckSheet").Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

or, if you know ***for sure*** that "User ID" string is to be found in active sheet row 1:

```
Sub FindthenCopy()
    Rows(1).Find(what:="User ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart).EntireColumn.Copy Worksheets("CheckSheet").Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sth like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCol()

Dim source As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
For i = 1 To 50
    If ws.Cells(1, i) = "User ID" Then
        ws.Columns(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Worksheets.Add 'Add new sheet
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select ' select a cell where your data 
  'suppose to be copy to
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'paste data
        Exit For

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```